# How to make mongos to be in a replica set?

Tags: mongodb

I have a shard cluster: one mongos, three shard replica sets and one config replica set. My application only talks to the `mongos` for read/write to mongodb. I wonder whether I can make the `mongos` replica. What I mean by this is that in case of a `mongos` is down, I need a slave of the mongos to become the primary. There is `--replSet` parameter on `mongod` but `mongos` doesn't have such parameter. How can I make it in mongos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have mongos as a replica set, it is just "proxy" between application and cluster. You can have multiple mongos-services. Normally you create mongos service to the same machine where you have the application. So, every application node has its own mongos and your application connects to that localhost mongos. If you mongos is down, your (single) application is down already, probably.

Of course, nothing prevents you to create multiple mongos nodes and put load balancer to the front of them. But I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: If I have multiple applications deployed in a cloud-based environment and they need to talk to the same mongos, based on your suggestion, each application has its own `mongos` process. And each `mongos` will have the same shards members. Is this correct?

Comment: Applications do not need to speak to same mongos! Every `mongos` takes its own connections to all primaries (config and shard). Needed information is exchanged between mongos.

Comment: Can one shard be added to multiple `mongos`?

Comment: You don't `add` shard to mongos. Every mongos connects every shard automatically, base on information what it gets from config server.

Comment: Can one shard server connect with multiple mongos? Since my mongos is running with the same server as my application server, and I have multiple app servers work as a replica set, I don't want all my app servers to talk to one `mongos` instance. So there is a need to create multiple mongos instances in my app system. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, one shard server can connect even hundreds of mongos. Setup, where every application server has local mongos running, is just normal setup. I have customer what have 10 shards and 60 mongos. No problem.